# Can not send mail with the gmail smtp and the swift mailer

Tags: php, smtp, gmail, swiftmailer

I cant send the email message via gmail smtp on swift mailer, here is the code:

```
<?php

require_once 'inc/swift_mailer/lib/swift_required.php';
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com', 465, 'ssl')
  ->setUsername('mysen2@gmail.com')
  ->setPassword('bestpasswordever')
  ;
$transport->setLocalDomain('[127.0.0.1]');
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

$message = Swift_Message::newInstance($transport)
  ->setSubject('Test Mail')
  ->setFrom(array('mysen2@gmail.com' => 'John Doe'))
  ->setTo(array('testin3@gmail.com'))
  ->setBody('This is the test message.')
  ->addPart('<q>Here is the message itself</q>', 'text/html');
  
    if (!$mailer->send($message, $failures))
    {
        die("Errors occurred:<br/>" . $failures);
    }

?>
```

And the error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Swift_TransportException' with
> message 'Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com
> [Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable
> it when you configured PHP? #-27264]' in
> /swift_mailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php:266
> Stack trace: #0
> /swift_mailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php(66):
> Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer->_establishSocketConnection() #1
> /swift_mailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php(117):
> Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer->initialize(Array) #2
> /swift_mailer/lib/classes/Swift/Mailer.php(79):
> Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->start() #3
> /usr/local/www/data/mail.php(19):
> Swift_Mailer->send(Object(Swift_Message), Array) #4 {main} thrown in
> /swift_mailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php
> on line 266

I guess its a problem with my server not containing the open ssl library:

> [Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable
> it when you configured PHP?

How can I fix that , then?

## also

Is using gmails SMTP good for sending like 50-100 mails per day? Or I should use something else (you're free to suggest and give me some tips)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fix the `[Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?` by recompiling PHP using the `--with-ssl[=DIR]` option.

In order to be able to do that, you have to install the OpenSSL libraries onto your server.  Depending on your OS, you can do something like `apt-get install openssl-dev` on Debian/Ubuntu, or `yum install openssl-devel` on RedHat/CentOS/Fedora.

Alternatively, you can just download and compile the latest version of [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/source/) yourself and use that with PHP.

If you do not run your server, then you need to ask your host to enable SSL in PHP for you.

**Also:** Gmail may work okay for sending 50-100 emails per day.  It depends though.  See their [Program Policies for Gmail](http://mail.google.com/mail/help/intl/en/program_policies.html) which does not go into a lot of detail.  It sounds like if you have a pre-existing relationship with the 50-100 people you are emailing per day, then you may not be violating any terms, but you may want to confirm that by contacting them directly or doing more searching about their terms.

Comment: I'm using freebsd so I got ports here :/

Comment: I don't have much experience with FreeBSD in recent years.  It looks like openssl-1.0.0_10 may be the port you want.  You will then have to find the PHP port that has SSL support, if one exists.